# Not able to handle const value having ternary operator check in jest framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I am working on creating an npm module. Using typescript and uses jest as testing framework.
But able to cover the info result condition mentioned in the code below.

index.ts

```
export const DEFAULT_LEVEL = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" ? "silent" : "info";

export something;
```

index.test.ts

```
import DEFAULT_LEVEL from "./index";
// Here i am getting the value as test for process.env.NODE_ENV.
// Instead i need to mock the value of process.env.NODE_ENV and check the value of DEFAULT_LEVEL

expect(DEFAULT_LEVEL).toBe("info"); // Now this is not happening
```

I am new to this and in the learning phase so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the defaults from the module; if you want to import just the constant `DEFAULT_LEVEL`, you need to wrap it in curly braces:

```js
import { DEFAULT_LEVEL } from "./index";
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import for more details.

---

Since you fixed that, I looked at your conditional again:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" ? "silent" : "info";
```

You return `silent` when the node env is `test`; just swap the conditions.

Comment: That is correct. I forgot to update it here. already performed it. But still the issue is there.